# Magento 2 : Catalog Layer has been already created

Tags: magento2, category, exception

On category page I am getting this exception

```
Catalog Layer has been already created
```

I tried to debug it in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Resolver.php, for the moment i commented the code that triggers exception

```
public function create($layerType)
{
    /*if (isset($this->layer)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Catalog Layer has been already created');
    }*/
    if (!isset($this->layersPool[$layerType])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException($layerType . ' does not belong to any registered layer');
    }
    $this->layer = $this->objectManager->create($this->layersPool[$layerType]);
}
```

Comment: Is there any third party extension use for the category layer navigation or something?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya think there's one from Amasty

Comment: Try to disable that one and then check.

Comment: @tarekfellah did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I don't remember

Comment: I have posted a debug method at another issue that might help to trace back this one too: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371101/110398](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371101/110398)